# Problema con cinemáticas en UE4

Tags: unreal-engine

cuando me dispongo a hacer una cinemática en sequencer con el add level sequence pongo los keyframes de track al inicio y al final, pero al reproducir la cinemática no hay resultado (no funciona).
¿Cómo puedo hacer las cinemáticas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para añadir un keyframe hay que darle al Enter a inicio y al final en el caso de carril de cámara y si es solo con Camera Actor hay que dar Enter en cada posición nueva que quieras guardar

Comment: No utilices la sección de respuestas para exponer parte de tu pregunta, puedes editar tu pregunta.